# Java how to add the Hero (object) to the game (class)

Tags: java

I have got a problem and I'm totally new at programming I have the object the Hero and I want to use all of his methods in my game class this is what I   Programmed so far:

**MainGame class:**

```
class MainGame extends JComponent implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    Image Background;

    MainGame() throws IOException {
        Background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Background.png"));
    }

    public static void  main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Adventure Times");
        MainGame game = new MainGame();
        window.add(game);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.addKeyListener(game);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(Background, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() { return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
        Hero.moveRight();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

**Hero class:**

```
public class Hero {

    public int HeroX = 0;
    public int HeroY = 0;
    public int HeroSpeed = 0;

    private BufferedImage Hero;

    public Hero() {

        try {
            Hero = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Hero.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void Draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(Hero, HeroX, HeroY, null);
    }

    public void moveRight() {
       HeroX += HeroSpeed;
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        HeroX -= HeroSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the code directly in the question instead of linking to it.

Comment: Please don't post links to 3rd party sites with your code. Post the relevant (key word, do not post the entire file please!) code here with a specific issue you are having

Comment: [Here is a guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html) on using Objects. Somewhere in your code you need to create a Hero object `Hero hector = new Hero();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `Hero`'s methods in your `MainGame` class, you either need an instance of `Hero` that can call them, or the method definitions have to include the `static` keyword.  In this application, `static` doesn't work, and would in fact completely break your `Hero` class if applied to the methods you have now, so you need to instantiate a `Hero`.  To do this, you need to, within `MainGame` have the line

```
Hero achilles = new Hero();
```

With the code you currently have, however, this will throw an exception in the `Hero` constructor that your `try` statement doesn't catch, as it won't be an `IOException`.  The exception will be a result of trying to assign a value to a data type in

```
Hero = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Hero.png"));
```

In fact, the code as it is won't even compile because of the attempted definition of `Hero` as a member of type `BufferedImage`.  This is illegal, as you cannot use a class name as an identifier.  This is similar to doing `int = 4`, which makes no sense.  Rename the `BufferedImage` wherever it's referred to and the code should compile.  For instance:

```
private BufferedImage sprite;
```

Alternatively, you could name it `hero` with a lowercase 'h' to avoid the name collision.  This is also in line with naming conventions and general best practice for Java, as well as most languages.  Class names are usually capitalized, while member names are usually lowercase.  For more info on naming conventions, [see here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help :)  I strongly recommend that you look over the [provided Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) from Oracle, they're what helped me learn Java.